# Replace 0 with empty cells using Python

Tags: python, excel

I have some data in csv format. The number of rows is 500 000 and columns 100. 95% cells are 0. I want to remove these 0's using python. How to do it?

For example the excel sheet reads:

```
0.861,0.885,0.769
0.284,0.000,0.000
0.383,0.313,0.000
```

I want it to look like following:

```
0.861,0.885,0.769
0.284
0.383,0.313
```

I want the cells with 0 to be empty in csv file

Comment: What have you tried already on your side? Could you provide the code you have at the moment that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: What if there is a non-zero value after a zero? Your example does not show that. And why not just do a text replacement?

Comment: 8.61E-01 8.85E-01 7.69E-01
2.84E-01 0.00E+00 0.00E+00
3.83E-01 3.13E-01 0.00E+00                                                                                                        i name it data.                                                                                                                             data[data==0] = '  '. I tried this

Comment: @Melebius: Thanks for asking. There can not be a non-zero value after 0 in the data. Even text occupies space so i want minimum size . As 95% of data is 0, better if it can be removed i.e. cells should be vacant.

Answer (score 0):

To have empty cells in your csv file, you have to replace 0 with nan

Just do this -

```
import numpy as np
df = df.replace(0, np.nan)
```

Output-

```
0.861 0.885 0.769
0.284   NaN   NaN
0.383 0.313   NaN
```

When you'll save the dataframe back to the csv file-

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

It will look like the desired output

Excel file-

```
0.861, 0.885, 0.769
0.284
0.383, 0.313
```

Comment: @uys happy to help!, if this solved your issue then accept this as an answer :)